# nmake of (OSRM v4.5.0) fails due to constexpr (C++11) with msvc12

Tags: c++11, openstreetmap, nmake, msvc12, osrm

I have an issue with OSRM back-end v4.5.0 build with nmake (see hereafter the error output). The "constexpr" in "Coordinate.h" is not supported by msvc12. 
**The question is, how to force cmake/nmake to use the CTP compiler !?**

Thanks for your reply

> Coordinate.h
>
> ```
> ... 
> namespace { 
> constexpr float COORDINATE_PRECISION = 1000000.f; 
> } 
> ...
> ```

Error output

> D:\osrm450be\build>nmake
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Scanning dependencies of target COORDINATE [  2%] Building CXX object
>   CMakeFiles/COORDINATE.dir/data_structures/Coordinate.cpp.obj
>   Coordinate.cpp D:\osrm450be\Include\osrm/Coordinate.h(37) : error
>   C2144: syntax error : 'float' should be preceded by ';'
>   D:\osrm450be\Include\osrm/Coordinate.h(37) : error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   D:\osrm450be\data_structures\Coordinate.cpp(290) : warning C4244: '='
>   : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data NMAKE :
>   fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return
>   code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the Visual Studio 2015 preview?  Are you using CMake 3.1?   According to [the release notes](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/release/3.1.0.html) there is a generator for it in that version.

Comment: I mean the [CTP compiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151) which is installed in my Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think using cmake with the following parameters:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" -T CTP_Nov2013 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ...
```

Answer (score 0):

one also need to define "__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS"